# ScalaTest+Selenium equivalent of .getText()

Tags: selenium, scalatest

I'm new to Selenium and ScalaTest, but I'm having issues finding Selenium+ScalaTest's counterpart to .getText()

For example, when I use selenium-java, I can retrieve text "Cat" by:

`driver.findElement(By.id("firstHeading")).getText()`

from:

`<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">Cat</h1>`

However, I can't figure out how to do this with ScalaTest, and my googling skills have failed me. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out one working solution:

`id("firstHeading").element.text should be ("Cat")`

This lets me extract the text from an element by the id "firstHeading". Please let me know if there is a better/more acceptable approach. Thanks!